# Creating a jQuery UI Dialog after click submit

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-ui-dialog, onsubmit

I have a form which calls `onSubmit="return report();"`. I have this javascript function in separate file. I would like to create my own jQuery UI Dialog instead of javascript confirm but I don't understand  jQuery at all. How should I change javascript function report() to obtain jQuery UI Dialog?

There is part of my php file:

```
<form method="POST" action="add.php" name="alert" id="alert" onSubmit="return report();">
    //some inputs
    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Send it</button>
```

And my js file:

```
 function report() {

    var report="Some text: \n\n";
    //There is code in simple javascript

    raport=raport+"\n";
    raport=raport+"If the are no mistakes click OK";
    return confirm(report);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not a friend of inline-javascript and you want to use jQUery I modified your code a bit.

This code will bind an event-listiner on the submit-button and prevent the default action (the submit in this case). If the user confirm the dialog the submit-event will be triggered manually.

```
$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var raport = "Some text: \n\n";
    //There is code in simple javascript
    raport = raport + "\n";
    raport = raport + "If the are no mistakes click OK";

    $("#dialog-confirm").text(raport).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $this.closest('form').submit();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1jekpcby/)**

**Reference**

[jQuery-UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

[dialog - buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[attribute-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. Is there anything like onSubmit in jQuery?

Comment: It goes into $('button[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) , but dialog doesn't show. Is it because I have my js functions in separate file? I don't understand it. I included this file to my php code

Comment: @KasiaM any errors appearing in your console ? Have you included the jquery-ui-library ?